# Link shared libraries in linux Public, Private and Interface

Tags: gcc, cmake, g++, shared-libraries

How can we link libraries public, private and interface through gcc or g++ the way it is done in CMake link target libraries Public, Private and Interface

Answer (score 0):

In CMake link keywords *PUBLIC*, *PRIVATE* and *INTERFACE* affects on **actual list of libraries**, used for linking one or another library/executable.

Because of that, these keywords are **transparent** for a compiler: they are *completely processed* without a compiler.